# Using Table on data frame by mutliple variables

Tags: r, reshape

I have a data table that is in a "long" format, containing many entries for each unique ID. For example...

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)  
date <- c("A","A","B","C","C","C")  
loc <- c("X", "X", "X", "X","Y","Z")  
dfTest <- data.frame(id,date,loc)
```

Which creates a sample table.

```
  id date loc
1  1    A   X
2  1    A   X
3  1    B   X
4  2    C   X
5  2    C   Y
6  2    C   Z
```

My goal is to create a table that looks like this.

```
id   X   Y   Z
1    2   0   0
2    1   1   1
```

I would like to see how many times a location was visited uniquely. ID#1 visited  X on day A and day B, giving a total unique visits of 2. I approached this using reshape, thinking to turn this into a "wide" format. However, I don't know how to factor in the second variable (the date). I'm trying to pull out the number of visits to each location on unique dates. The actual date itself otherwise does not matter, just that it identify the duplicate entries.

My current solution would be poor form in R (to use iterative loops to look at locations found within each unique date). I was hoping reshape, apply, aggregate, or perhaps another package may be of more help. I've looked through a bunch of other reshape guides, but am still a bit stuck on the clever way to do this.

Comment: Are you just looking for `table(unique(dfTest)[-2])` perhaps?

Comment: That's perfect — I'm a newbie to R, and figured I was working to hard. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the sounds of it, you should be able to do what you need with:

```
table(unique(dfTest)[-2])
##    loc
## id  X Y Z
##   1 2 0 0
##   2 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can group by 'loc', 'id', get the `length` of `unique` elements of 'date' and use `dcast` to get the expected output.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
dcast(setDT(dfTest)[, uniqueN(date), .(loc, id)], id~loc, value.var='V1', fill=0)
#   id X Y Z
#1:  1 2 0 0
#2:  2 1 1 1
```

Comment: I'll give this a try as well — the file I'm working on is about ~300k entries, so perhaps this will run faster.

Comment: @asshah4 The `dcast` from `data.table` is very fast.